# Overscroll 'glow' not working on scrollable div (in webview)?

Tags: android, html, css

I'm having some issues getting the 'overscroll glow' to work on a scrollable div.

The first problem is finding answers or documentation on this because this thing has a lot of names, I'm not entirely sure what the correct term is and most of them I tried confuse google (i get a lot of results for 'overflow:auto;' etc). So for clarity, here's an image of the effect I'm looking for:

[image: look, it's overscroll glow!]

Anyway, my problem is this: I did have this effect when my html/body elements were scrollable but when I moved things to divs (in this case the .content element), it stopped working.

Something like this:

```
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.appbar {
    position: absolute;
    top:0; left:0; right:0;
    height:56px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top:56px; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.make-it-scrollable {
    height:200%;
}

<body>
<div class="appbar"></div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="make-it-scrollable"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

On iOS I get the elastic 'rubber banding' effect when I try to scroll past the content (thanks to the -webkit-overflow-scrolling) but on Android I get nothing.

Is this by design? (meaning: is the overscroll effect disabled or 'not implemented' for divs with overflow:x?

Or am I missing something?

Oh btw I'm testing this on Android 5.1 with the latest Chromium based webview (it's a cordova app)

Comment: I found an article on how to implement this 'manually' with css/javascript: http://derekknox.com/articles/material-design-overscroll-in-vanilla-js/ but I'm hoping this can be achieved on a 'native' level - by that I mean the browser should be able to handle this, right?

Comment: Looks like it's not possible; there is an open issue on the chromium bug tracker that covers this issue (actually flagged as a bug). It's been open for a while (apr 2014) but last updates are from june so I haven't given up hope yet.. Link: "Overscroll glow for scrollable sublayers" https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=365804

Comment: Did this work ?

Comment: Did this work? In the past? No, I don't think so..